How to test django channels between two physical devices over a wifi network
Can someone help me configure my django channel app in order for me to be able to test the chatting feature between two users. They must use two different devices and chat over a wifi network
Looking through the net I can't find anything

As long as you setup the server to run asgi instead of wsgi, the steps taken here are the same. Follow the docs to run your server in asgi mode.
